# Removing swagger from ServiceStack WSDL

Tags: c#, wsdl, servicestack

I have a REST & SOAP API implementation in ServiceStack and I am having a problem with getting rid of Swagger in the WSDL.

I have the swagger plugin installed with servicestack with:

```
Plugins.Add(new SwaggerFeature());
```

I've documented everything rest side that I'm using and the swagger works well.  I'm getting this kind of thing in the WSDL:

```
<xs:complexType name="ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringSwaggerModelEdXdwojR">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:appinfo>
<IsDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">true</IsDictionary>
</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="KeyValueOfstringSwaggerModelEdXdwojR">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Key" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element xmlns:q1="http://me.com/schemas/2015/05/API/" name="Value" nillable="true" type="q1:SwaggerModel"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I'd like to remove it because I can't see the use of it. Anyone know what the use is?  And also how to remove?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to exclude Services from SOAP by annotating the Request DTO's with the `[Exclude(Feature.Soap)]` attribute. Because their built-in Services you can use the runtime attribute dynamic API, e.g:

```
typeof (ResourceRequest)
    .AddAttributes(new ExcludeAttribute(Feature.Soap));
```